# Resharper does not detect visual studio 2015 is installed

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015, resharper-9.0

I have Visual Studio 2015 community edition, it works just fine.

I now try to install the newest version of resharper, but it says I don't have VS2015.

I tried to repair visual studio but resharper still does not detect it.

How can I install resharper for VS2015?

BTW I'm using windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried Administrative Mode, it gave me the following command line: `JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.2.exe /VsVersion=14 /SpecificProductNames=ReSharper /Silent=True` which I ran as administrator and it did nothing.

Comment: youd prob be much better off reaching out to jetbrains directly.

Comment: I use JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016 3.2 in VS2015. I installed it and after applying the license and etc.. then I searched ReSharper in tools=>options. I suspended it once and again resumed that. then I closed the visual studio and reopened it. Then I saw the resharper in my main menu.

Comment: The thing is, resharper can sometimes think that you have no VS installed and therefore refuse to be installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yay, I solved it!

The problem was that for some reason I didn't have permissions for the registry key `VisualStudio.DTE.14.0`. This is the key that tells resharper whether VS2015 is installed or not.

To get my permissions back I did what this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/56fed319-a532-46a4-a384-fd795998c4a3/regedit-permissions-access-denied-or-error-while-deleting-key-even-as-admin?forum=w7itproinstall) says:
I downloaded sysinternals and used `psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe` to gain full access.

Then I added permissions to myself (right click on that registry key, then `permissions` and so on).

And after that the resharper could tell I have VS2015 installed!

Another [helpful tip](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/23657) given by JetBrains (thanks @iamkrillin for telling me to ask them directly) is to check `%localappdata%\JetBrains\Shared\v03` for the installation logs.

I'm really glad it worked =)

Comment: Thank you for this! I had the same problem and setting permissions helped me as well. To add some more specific details to the process, the key can be found in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes and you must right-click on the key in the tree view on the left in order to get permissions. Then I had to add my specific username and give full control (not just giving full control to the system, admin, etc. roles).